# Bifurcate "Why isn't this code working" and "without a clear problem statement"

Tags: discussion

When we vote to close some question, we get some options, like duplicate, off-topic, unclear what you are asking ...

In the "off topic" section, we get some options (we all can see them, so I am not writing them down). The fourth option says:

> Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Now, this option itself, is a combination of :

- "*Questions seeking debugging help*" eg: [Eg1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29155716/why-is-this-not-working), [Eg2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20201417/why-is-this-not-working), [Eg3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14121900/why-is-this-loop-not-working)
- "*Questions without a clear problem statement*" eg: [Eg1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37147004/java-undirected-tree), [Eg2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37093035/how-to-solve-this-error-of-eclipse)

(Don't visit those links. They are rubbish.)

In *my* opinion, we should bifurcate this option into the two above mentioned parts, or maybe remove the second part, as we already have "*unclear what you are asking*" in the original menu.

Comment: _"(Do visit those links. They are rubbish and need to be closed.)"_

Comment: @Cerbrus 2 of them are already closed. 1 is on-hold!, But, is that why this is downvoted?

Comment: The two bullet points effectively convey the same meaning: post a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve): which means, posting the code in minimal form (Minimal) while making sure all the info is there (Complete) and describing what is going wrong with a problem statement (Verifiable).

Comment: @Tunaki The parts I bolded are bolded in the original text in the close dialog box. That is why I bolded them.

Comment: The first "Questions without a clear problem statement" was closed as "Unclear what you're asking", which is the proper close reason for questions which are unclear. The second asked about an error specifically, which follows the "debugging help" closer than "clear problem statement".

Comment: OK. So one thing I am sure about, after this post - People certainly do what they re told not to! :P

Answer (score 3):

This proposal doesn't make sense, because asking for debugging help isn't off topic in and of itself. It's only inappropriate when you ask for debugging help without providing a complete code sample fit for debugging, which is what this close reason describes.